# Applying Styles Android

Tags: android, dialog, themes, styles

I want to make my Activity appear like a Dialog box, but without the title bar. So I think I should write this style myself.

But how should this XML style be?

I already tried the Theme.Dialog for my Activity, but the thing is, I don't want the background of the Theme.Dialog style. And without an label for screen. 
I has all the screen build by XML, I want just center it on screen and has a semi-transparent outside background.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do this

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" 
android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" 
android:label="Gana"/>
```

> res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog"> 
 <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
 <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
 <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
 <item name="android:background">@drawable/mybackground</item>
 <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
 <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
 <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
 <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
 <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
 <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
 <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
 <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>

</style>
```

If you don't want background remove that.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want the background of the Theme.Dialog style. And without an label for screen. I has all the screen build by XML, I want just center it on screen and has a semi-transparent outside background.

Comment: I'm going to try it soon. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't works as expected I not only the border of the background continue to appears (I changed background to #FF000000) and also my Layout was not getting in the layout I described.

Comment: else also add this in your style.xml  '<item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>'

Comment: This is almost done, but a last thing, how I remove the white border from it?

Comment: now i have edited my answer by adding extra parameters to that style.xml so you can use that activity without border .that's it.. done. also accept my answer dude.

Comment: I'm going to accept it as soon my problem was solved. Don't worry.

Comment: I got it just by only having the `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>` bit