# Changing AlertDialog.Builder button color

Tags: android, android-dialog

Im trying to change the button color of AlertDialog.Builder but i didnt find a way to do it.

I want to change the color of the buttons and the title to white like in HOLO theme.

see these 2 screenshots for examples:

[image]

[image]

Ive looked here:

[How to change theme for AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog)

[Change the style of AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011899/change-the-style-of-alertdialog)

[How to change the background of the custom alert dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735869/how-to-change-the-background-of-the-custom-alert-dialog)

[Applying Styles Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473822/applying-styles-android)

All of them are not working for me.

Here is my code:

```
public void logInDialog()
{
    ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper( this,  R.style.dialogStyle);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctw);
    builder.setTitle("Log in");
    View prefView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.log_in, null);  
    //The rest of the code.........
}
```

This is my style code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="dialogStyle" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:button">@color/white</item>
    </style>    
</resources>
```

Answer (score 19):

I know this is a very old question, but I came across with the same problem and I found a solution.
In order to change the color of the text inside a button of an Alert dialog you should do something like this:

```
public void logInDialog()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    //setting custom view for our dialog
    View myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_CUSTOM_LAYOUT, null);
    builder.setNeutralButton(android.R.string.cancel, null);
    builder.setView(myview);

    //creating an alert dialog from our builder.
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

    //retrieving the button view in order to handle it.
    Button neutral_button = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);

    Button positive_button = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);


    if (neutral_button != null) {
        neutral_button.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_background));

        neutral_button.setTextColor(context.getResources()
                        .getColor(android.R.color.white));
    }
    if (positive_button != null) {
        positive_button.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_background));

        positive_button.setTextColor(context.getResources()
                        .getColor(android.R.color.white));
    }

}
```

And the xmls for your button used :

custom_background.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="#000000"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selectable_item_background"/>

</layer-list>
```

And selectable_item_background.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_focused" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

I personally used this code inside a Fragment, this is why I have a LayoutInflater. In your case you can skip this step.
Hope it helps other people in the future.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on @Ioumaros's answer, setBackgroundDrawable is now deprecated. You can achieve the same background colour change with this code:

```
    Button negativeButton = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
    negativeButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBackground));

    Button positiveButton = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    positiveButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBackground));
```

But doing this programatically isn't usually considered the best way...

Answer (score 0):

To Change the buttons Color of the AlertDialog.

```
// Initialize AlertDialog & AlertDialog Builder
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
builder.setTitle(R.String.AlertDialogTitle);
...........
......... 
//Build your AlertDialog 
AlertDialog Demo_alertDialog= builder.create();
Demo_alertDialog.show();

//For Positive Button:
Button b_pos; 
b_pos=Demo_alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
if(b_pos!=null){
   b_pos.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.YourColor));
   }    


//For Neutral Button:
Button b_neu;
b_neu=Demo_alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
if(b_neu!=null){
   b_neu.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.YourColor));
   }

//For Negative Button:
Button b_neg;
b_neg=Demo_alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
if(b_neg!=null){
   b_neg.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.YourColor));
   }
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

**after** alertDialog.show();

```
Button buttonNegative= alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);  
buttonNegative.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

or

```
buttonNegative.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```